# run installed apk file from local storage

Tags: android

I am developing android application its about run of apk file. I can download apk file to my local storage but I can't run this apk file How can I run installed apk file in android? I tried below code but I got a error

```
public class DownloadApkMainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_download_apk_main);

        Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        installIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        installIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("/mnt/sdcard/" + "/MyFavorite/"+ "Anket4.apk"), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        startActivity(installIntent);
    }


}
```

Comment: "I tried below code but I got a error" -- what is the error?

Comment: I got a error like this ,There was a problem parsing package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
installIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("/mnt/sdcard/" + "/MyFavorite/"+ "Anket4.apk"), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
```

try

```
installIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("/mnt/sdcard/" + "/MyFavorite/"+ "Anket4.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
```

Comment: I'm glad that I could help